# Working with avg, to_char, and having

Tags: mysql

Display the department ID, average salary (in currency format), and the number of job IDs for each department. Limit the results to only those departments with more than 5 job IDs.

What I've tried so far.

select department_id, to_char(avg(salary, '$999,999.00')), count(job_id)
from employees
group by department_id, salary, job_id
having SUM(job_id) > '5';

I'm having trouble understand what it means by "invalid number of arguments."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only `department_id` should be appearing in the `GROUP BY` clause since you want to aggregate over departments, and not anything else.

```
SELECT department_id,
       CONCAT('$', FORMAT(AVG(salary), 2)) AS avg_salary,
       COUNT(*) AS num_job_ids
FROM employees
GROUP BY department_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```

I assumed in my answer that every `job_id` in the table is unique.  If this is not the case, and you wanted to instead count/report unique jobs, then you can replace `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(DISTINCT job_id)`.